# PHP: Is addslashes() also valid for echo-ed HTML/JS strings?

Tags: php, escaping

I am not expert with PHP, but I have to cover for the following situation:

```
<?php

  ...

  if ($some_condition_is_met) {
    echo ' ...a lot of HTML/JS statements I ...';
  } else {
    echo ' ...a lot of HTML/JS statements II...';
  }

?>
```

My issue is that the HTML/JS statements contain both single and double quotes. Can I use the [addslashed()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) method to escape those echoed statements properly (it is used for database statements)? Or is there another valid method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: what do you need the slashes for? Unless you're preparing a string for use in an SQL statement, there's no point in escaping with slashes (even if addslashes wasn't utterly broken should NEVER be used for database operations). For output into an html environment, you should be using htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.

Comment: Please use something less manual than mysql_real_escape_string. Running each variable through an escape function and then concatenating it into a string leaves too much room for programmer error.